# Impulse response stablity in a VAR model

Tags: self-study, vector-autoregression, impulse-response

I am trying to fit a 3 variable VAR model and I need to check if the
qualitative features of impulse responses are approximately stable across subsamples. But I am not sure what impulse response stability is and how to check if they are stable. Can someone explain it to me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could graph the impulse responses for the different subsamples and see if they look similar, e.g. see if the response of one subsample fits into the 95% confidence interval of another subsample. That could be justified by the task formulation containing the expression *qualitative features*.

If you needed to assess that quantitatively, you would perhaps look directly at the models for each subsample and test whether they are very different (e.g. in terms of Kullback-Leibler distance or the like).